# Confusion-matrix clarification from Python

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

```
confusion_matrix(y_test1, pred)
That is my codes 

Confusion matrix, without normalization
True     [[724258    438]
value    [ 25396    302]]
          Predicted value
```

I understand that is how this is the confusion matrix. But I do not know the order of classification result.

```
0   [[724258    438]                1 [[724258    438]
1   [ 25396    302]]                0 [ 25396    302]]
       0         1                        1        0
```

Which order generally? I check the documentation, it does not tell me the specific result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's the first one

```
0   [[724258    438]       
1   [ 25396    302]]      
       0         1
```

According to the documentation

```
sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=None, sample_weight=None)
```

> labels : array, shape = [n_classes], optional List of labels to index
>   the matrix. This may be used to reorder or select a subset of labels.
>   If none is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred
>   are used in sorted order.

Comment: I am also curious what Happen if it is three labels such as 0, 1, 2. Will still follow like that?

Comment: yup,  "If none is given, those that appear at least once in y_true or y_pred are used in """"sorted order"""""